# LINQ - trying to use Include, custom Function and return custom type. Include does not work

Tags: c#, linq, objectcontext

I'm new to LINQ, so there is probably a simple answer to this, but I have a function to get all locations within a specified radius, including the distance calculated AND (here's the part that doesn't work) use the INCLUDE function to get a related object. I tried using join and INCLUDE because I actually read somewhere that they give different results, but I couldn't get either to work. Here are both I tried:

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
      // Using custom Function udf_Haversine defined in DB
      var query = (from cl in db.restaurant
                  join cg in db.reviews on cl.review_id equals cg.id
                  where (cl.longitude > lng_min && cl.longitude < lng_max)
                  && (cl.latitude > lat_min && cl.latitude < lat_max)
                  && (cl.active == true)
                  select new ObjectGeoLocationDTO
                  {
                      myObject = cl,
                      Distance = ModelDefinedFunctions.udf_Haversine(origLat, origLng, cl.latitude, cl.longitude)
                  });

      return query.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Distance > 10);
}
```

and my other attempt using INCLUDE: (what's throwing me off is having to include the Distance values that's calculated from my custom function. If not for that wrench in the system, I know the simple INCLUDE method will neatly get all my reviews just as part of my restaurant object)

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
        var query = db.restaurant
                      .Where(cl => cl.longitude > lng_min)
                      .Where(cl => cl.longitude < lng_max)
                      .Where(cl => cl.latitude > lat_min)
                      .Where(cl => cl.latitude < lat_max)
                      .Include(cl => cl.review)
                      .Select(cl => new ObjectGeoLocationDTO 
                           {
                               myObject = cl,
                               Distance = ModelDefinedFunctions.udf_Haversine(origLat, origLng, cl.latitude, cl.longitude)
                           });

        return query.ToList().RemoveAll(x => x.Distance > 10);
}
```

And the ObjectGeoLocationDTO is defined as:

```
public class ObjectGeoLocationDTO
{
    public Object myObject { get; set; }
    public decimal Distance { get; set; }
}
```

(I used a generic object because I wanted to be able to use this for more than just the "restaurants", but also for the "schools" and other tables). SO, BOTH of these variations work great - EXCEPT for the fact that they aren't actually including the related object ("reviews"). So I'm getting the

> ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

error whenever I try to access the reviews via

```
List<ObjectGeoLocationDTO>objGeo = //call query;
((restaurant)objGeo[0].myObject).review.description
```

Now, here's the strange thing. I would've just tossed the whole solution as faulty and tried looking for another way to do this, but it seems to work...sometimes! As in, when I'm debugging and stepping through the process it works! It's very confusing. So I get 25 rows back, and as I'm stepping through it, sometimes my code will process 6 objects in the list before giving me that error because the "review" object isn't available for it. Sometimes, I only get past 3. It seems to depend on how fast I'm debugging. However, whenever I just run the code straight without debugging it always fails on the first object in the list.

So, if anyone can help me, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get the "review" object to be included in the "restaurant" object?
2. Why in the world does it partially work while I'm debugging?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question:

> How do I get the "review" object to be included in the "restaurant" object?

You can execute the query before the *Select* method, because your Select does nothing on database.
So:

1. Create restaurants query including *Reviews* property
2. Execute query using ToSomething()
3. You can dispose your dbContext now
4. Use Select method on in-memory data(LINQ to Objects)

Here is your code tuned(not sure if compiles):

```
Restaurant[] restaurants = null;

using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
    restaurants = db.restaurant
                    .Where(cl => cl.longitude > lng_min)
                    .Where(cl => cl.longitude < lng_max)
                    .Where(cl => cl.latitude > lat_min)
                    .Where(cl => cl.latitude < lat_max)
                    .Include(cl => cl.review)
                    .ToArray();
}

var geoLocations = restaurants
                .Select(cl => new ObjectGeoLocationDTO
                {
                    myObject = cl,
                    Distance = ModelDefinedFunctions.udf_Haversine(origLat, origLng, cl.latitude, cl.longitude)
                });

return geoLocations.Where(x => x.Distance <= 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

.ToList() should do the trick forcing the query to run

```
using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
{
        return db.restaurant
                      .Where(cl => cl.longitude > lng_min)
                      .Where(cl => cl.longitude < lng_max)
                      .Where(cl => cl.latitude > lat_min)
                      .Where(cl => cl.latitude < lat_max)
                      .Include(cl => cl.review)
                      .ToList()
                      .Select(cl => new ObjectGeoLocationDTO {
                          myObject = cl,
                          Distance = ModelDefinedFunctions.udf_Haversine(origLat, origLng, cl.latitude, cl.longitude)
                      })
                      .Where(d=>d.Distance <= 10)
                      .ToList();
}
```